# MVC If login failed not redirecting to correct path, but to /Account/Login?ReturnUrl

Tags: .net, redirect, model-view-controller

I'm trying to redirect the user if the login is not correct to path ~/Login/Index but it redirects it to /Account/Login?ReturnUrl…

I'm using cookies to store the identity of the user.

I've tried already a few solutions I found here like:

Adding these lines in web.config, even if I think i should modify the appsettings.json for the appSettings section but I'm not finding any examples.

```cs
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<appSettings>
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Login/Index" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Settings in Startup.cs in ConfigureServices are

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
```

and in Configure are

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

The method which I'm using to save the cookies is:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.UserName) }, 
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
var login = HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
```

and to delete is:

```
var login = HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

To chose which controllers are available for the users I'm using the [Authorize] "command".

Thanks to anyone who is willing to help me and tell me if I need to add more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by editing the code in ConfigureServices from:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
```

to:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
            });
```

Now it redirects to the correct path but the ?ReturnUrl is still there.